# Getting YouTube back on Apple TV

Tags: appletv, youtube

As of the latest Apple TV software update, YouTube is no longer showing up on the home screen, apparently replaced by Vimeo (which I like, but which has a very limited video selection). Is there any way to get YouTube back on the Apple TV home screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have turned off YouTube under Settings -> General -> Privacy.  Check there, and then toggle it back to SHOW.  If this was the problem, please "Accept" the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Apple has removed YouTube.  Try logging out of your iTunes account, then back in.

Answer (score 0):

Which generation Apple TV is this on? YouTube has been removed from all but the 3rd gen hardware as Google retired the API in use as of April 20 2015   ([Announcement](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2015/04/bye-bye-youtube-data-api-v2.html))

Comment: This question is almost three years old and no longer relevant. I no longer have the AppleTV in question.

Answer (score -2):

You can't get this YouTube channel back until Google re opens its streaming feed API for older devices.  They probably won't until they can rewrite it to incorporate in-stream ads.

Comment: Take a look at the already-posted answers and you'll notice there's an accepted solution to the problem already.